# Youtube Video Tutorial - Geotagging App

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

Following this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNMNRAbIDoU&list=PL56E5A96A1ADE139D&index=1&feature=plpp_video&fmt=18), I got to the end stages of coding the map app.

when I got to type about `viewControllers.mapView` I got syntax error of:

**'unknown receiver 'viewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?'**

I am running **XCode version 4.4.1**

I believe the tutorial to be using a previous version.

Comment: Please post the actual code. It'll make it much easier to help.

Comment: There is a bit of code in several classes.. how would I show this best?

Comment: Pull out the relevant sections and put each in a separate code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created viewController method and it worked.